# A workbook recommendation for numerical linear algebra

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, book-recommendation

Is there any good book I could use as a workbook for following topics (or covers some of them):

- Gaussian method of elimination
- LU factorization with GME
- Doolittle's and Kraut's method
- Factorization of Cholesky
- GME with partial pivoting
- Gauss - Jordan's method for solving system Ax = b
- Condition number of a system
- Conditions for convergence of iterative methods
- Jacoby's method
- Gauss - Seidel's method
- Gerschgorin's sets and theorem
- Power method and inversive power method for eigenvalues
- QR factorization for eigenvalues
- Method of normal equations

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It appears you should first learn some linear algebra (by choosing any basic linear algebra text. You can check textbook recommendations for linear algebra on this site). This will give you the tools to learn many of the other topics on your list elsewhere. Unfortunately, many topics on your list will probably be in a numerical methods textbook, and might be a bit more complicated to understand. But for instance Apostol's Linear Algebra --> Atkinson's Numerical Analysis would cover almost everything on this list.

Comment: Thank you. I will check for the book.  I have already took both introductory and advanced course in linear algebra, abstract algebra and multivariable calculi. Just, this semester I am having Numerical linear algebra and numerical analysis courses, and both require "hand solved" problems and problems in a mathematical-oriented programming language. So I was looking for problems I could use to work those problems by hand.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that "Numerical linear algebra" by Trefethen and Bau has all of it covered, both explained and for work.